# how would you find multiple items in a list from one word in python

Tags: python

I am still very new to python and having trouble with this code. the idea is that you can input a persons first name, last name, age, and gender, and save it in a list. then retrieve all the data about a person just by entering their first name. I have tried a couple of different things like using the collection library but nothing has worked so far. any help would be great.
code:

```
person =[]

cl = input(": ")

if cl == "new.person":
    newpersonfname = input("first name: ")
    newpersonlname = input("last name: ")
    newpersonage = str(int(input("age: ")))
    newpersongen = str(input("first letter of gender(f, m, nb, o): "))
    value = "{", newpersonfname, newpersonlname, newpersonage, newpersongen, "}"
    person.extend(value)
    print("successfuly added")

if cl == "retrieve.person.by.name":
    RPBN = str(input("name(first): "))
    #???
```

Comment: Seems like you might be interested in learning about [Python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) like so:

```
person = {}

cl = input(": ")

if cl == "new.person":
    newpersonfname = input("first name: ")
    newpersonlname = input("last name: ")
    newpersonage = str(int(input("age: ")))
    newpersongen = str(input("first letter of gender(f, m, nb, o): "))
    person['newpersonfname'] = {'newpersonlname':newpersonlname, 'newpersonage':newpersonage,'newpersongen':newpersongen}
    print("successfuly added")

if cl == "retrieve.person.by.name":
    RPBN = str(input("name(first): "))
    print(person[RPBN])
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @aaossa comment. If you are asked to do it only with a list. You can take a input for the first name from the user, equate it to the List[1] and if it matches, display the rest of the contents of the list. I do however recommed using Dictonary for such tasks.

```
person = {}

cl = input(": ")

if cl == "new.person":
    newpersonfname = input("first name: ")
    newpersonlname = input("last name: ")
    newpersonage = str(int(input("age: ")))
    newpersongen = str(input("first letter of gender(f, m, nb, o): "))
    value = "{", newpersonfname, newpersonlname, newpersonage, newpersongen, "}"
      person.extend(value)
    print("successfuly added")

if cl == "retrieve.person.by.name":
    RPBN = str(input("name(first): "))
    if value[1].equals(RPBN):
        for i=2; i<len(value)-1; i++ :
            print(value[i]);
```